# Monitoring Zombie processes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring, zombie-process, zabbix

Currently Nagios monitors zombie processes with this command:

```
$USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c check_procs_status -a $ARG1$ $ARG2$ $ARG3$
```

It checks for zombie processes with state = X,Z. From a Linux or Ubuntu machine, I can run this command to view Zombie processes:

```
ps aux | grep 'X'
```

How to do I get both 'X' and 'Z' state in one line. I want to configure same monitor in Zabbix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep -E` or `egrep` for multiple matches:

```
ps aux | grep -E 'X|Z'
```

As per your [suggested review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3206189) I see that you want the 8th column to be either "X" or "Y". For that, you can do:

```
ps aux | awk '$8=="X" || $8=="Y"'
```

#### Example

```
$ cat a
hello
bye
blabla bye
other things
$ grep -E 'bye|hello' a
hello
bye
blabla bye
```

Comment: Hmmm just realized that the two suggested commands displays anything with X & Z in it even if its not a zombie process

Comment: What exact syntax did you use?

Comment: exactly what you suggested

Comment: I have attached s screenshot to your edit but it says it must be peer reviewed

Comment: OK now I see what you mean. Check my updated answer. I work with `awk` and with the fact that the STATUS value is stored in the 8th column.

Comment: OK that seems to make sense. I also added at the end "| wc -l" and it returned 0 but obviously no way i can test without having zombie processes running

Comment: Good. Cross check if the status on your `ps aux` output is also 8th column. If not, change the `$8` for `$n`, being n the line number. I checked with `Sl` status and worked.

Comment: By the way, don't forget you can accept an answer if you are done!

Answer (score 1):

/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 5 -c 10 -s Z,X

Answer (score 0):

```
ps aux | grep 'X\|Z'
```

It should grep on X or Z

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in multiple ways. I propose something like:

```
ps -eo stat,pid,cmd | grep ^Z
```